# Why am I not able to establish a session on my project on AngularJS, php & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I am working on a login system using `AngularJS`,`php`, and`MySQL`. I am following [this tutorial](http://softaox.info/angularjs/angularjs-user-signup-and-login-authentication-using-php-mysql/) on creating an `AngularJS` user signup and login authentication using `php` & `MySQL`.  When I put it on "live", I get the error message below:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) angularlogin/files/functions/session:1 Failed to load
>   resource:

I have checked my `phpinfo` for session, which is is enabled. What is wrong?

Comment: Hi Ravi!  Can you clarify what files you see under `angularlogin/files/functions/`?  Can you see the files on a web browser?

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Not the definite answer (comments are too limited), but I spun up the project you linked to, I get almost the same error:

angular.min.js:77 GET .../files/functions/session 500 (Internal Server Error)

But a 500, not 404 so you probably need to give us more info. 404 (file not found) could mean you have forgotten to copy some files?

Anyway:

1. You can always check the server logs, I got `ErrorException: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'angularjs_login'`. If this is your problem, you've just forgotten to create the database on the server.
2. During development, don't use the production angularjs (`angular.min.js`), instead use the non-minified version (`angular.js`) because you'll get much better error messages!
3. Open the network tab in your browser dev-tools (press F12), click the failed request (sessions) marked in red when not selected, and if your php-settings allows it, you can see the the error straight away under the preview-tab.
   [image]

---

### If you are sure you have copied all files, here is a qualified guess:

Your webserver is not configured for slim. Which requires all requests to go through the main `index.php`, in your case `files/functions/index.php`. If there is a request to say `files/functions/session` (which does not exist), the webserver will redirect that request to index.php which sorts the request and passes it along to the right place.

If the request does not go through index.php, then you'll get a 404-error.

Slim solves does this by using a .htaccess-file. `files/functions/.htaccess`. On windows it might be a hidden file, which could be a reason you've missed it.

Or, your webserver is configurated to not care about .htaccess-files, then you have to change your webserver settings.

Or, you have a webserver that doesn't use .htaccess-files at all, (like nginx) then you have to find another way to redirect those requests. I suggest you have a look at https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html

There is too little info for us to know for sure, but I think the above seems somewhat likely anyway.

Comment: no, i am not forgotten save file or .htaccess file are in the same directory.
if you want i am share my cpanel credential to you.